# Read XML by xpath containing namespace prefix

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmldocument

im trying to read from this 
http://api.hostip.info/?ip=12.215.42.19

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

xml.Load("http://api.hostip.info/?ip=79.177.176.8");

XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("gml:featureMember/Hostip");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    string Name = xn["countryName"].InnerText;
    MessageBox.Show(Name);
}
```

im getting a weird error

> Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This
>   query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.

never seen something like that before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to, first, define mapping of namespace prefix to namespace uri, before you can use the prefix in your xpath. In this case, use `XmlNamespaceManager` to define the mapping, then you can simply pass the namespace manager instance as 2nd parameter of `SelectNodes()` :

```
......
var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
//register mapping of prefix to namespace uri 
nsManager.AddNamespace("gml", "http://www.opengis.net/gml");
//pass the namespace manager instance as 2nd param of SelectNodes():
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("HostipLookupResultSet/gml:featureMember/Hostip", nsManager);
......
```

There is another problem in your xpath. `gml:featureMember` is not the root element of the XML, it is the root's child. So you need to mention the root element before `gml:featureMember` as demonstrated above, or alternatively using `descendant-or-self` axis like : `//gml:featureMember/Hostip` (the latter would be *a bit* slower though).